# Onesignal - How to send a push notification to android device using python?

Tags: python, onesignal

I am trying to send a push notifications to all subscribed users.

Depending on [onesignal api documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification), the content must be a valid language which i really don't understand!! why i should send the data like as mentioned in the documentation

`contents : {"en":"English Text!}`

Here is my python code :

```
import requests
import json

header = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Authorization": "Basic xxxx"
}

payload = {
            "app_id": "xxxx",
            "included_segments": ["All"],
            "contents":{"en":"notification","ru":"уведомление"}
            "data": {
                "body": "Hello my friend! we added a new post!",
                "fromProjectNumber": "xxxxxx",
                "groupKey": "myapp_grp",
                "groupMessage": "MyApp",
                "largeIcon": "https://example.com/icon.png",
                "lockScreenVisibility": 1,
                "priority": 5,
                "smallIcon": "icon",
                "title": "New post",
            }
        }

req = requests.post("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications", headers=header, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

I am receiving the notification, but no data shows up! in fact, i am getting only the text in contents.

Answer (score 4):

Finally i recognized that the payload that i am sending is incorrect, this how it should looks like:

```
payload = {
    "app_id": "xxxx",
    "included_segments": ["All"],
    "contents": {"en": "Lorem ipsum dolor amit falit matit", "ru": "Lorem ipsum dolor amit falit matit"},
    "android_gcm_sender_id": "620941305752",
    "android_group": "myapp_grp",
    "android_group_message": "MyApp",
    "large_icon": "https://img.onesignal.com/n/icon.png",
    "android_visibility": 1,
    "priority": 5,
    "android_sound":"notification",
    "headings": {"en": "New post", "ru": "Мы опубликовали новую статью"}
}
```

Also, I've found a cool python library for sending push notifications through Onesignal [A Python client library for OneSignal API.](https://pypi.org/project/onesignal-sdk), this code is working as needed:

```
payload = {
    "included_segments": ["All"],
    "contents": {"en": "Lorem ipsum dolor amit ", "ru": "Lorem ipsum dolor amit"},
    "android_gcm_sender_id": "XXXX",
    "android_group": "myapp_grp",
    "android_group_message": "MyApp",
    "large_icon": "https://img.onesignal.com/n/icon.png",
    "android_visibility": 1,
    "priority": 5,
    "android_sound":"notification",
    "headings": {"en": "New post NazarNews TV", "ru": "Мы опубликовали новую статью"}
}

# create a onesignal client
onesignal_client = onesignal_sdk.Client(
    app_auth_key="XXXX",
    app_id="XXXX"
)

# create a notification
new_notification = onesignal_sdk.Notification(post_body=payload)

# Send notification
onesignal_response = onesignal_client.send_notification(new_notification)
```

But i don't know why there is no notification sound!

Comment: is it possible to customize notification like, if I want to change the color of a
particular text, change the size of font?

Comment: Try to add an HTML tags inside your contents and see if it works!